# Combine Hibernate Queries Without Table Scan

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

A bit of background - I am on Hibernate 3.5 (which, most relevantly, does not have unions.) I have Items, and I have Tags. Tags are stored as sets in Items. I am trying to edit our database search component so that I can search for an Item by a string that can be either the name of an Item or the name of a Tag. Effectively, I have two queries:

```
select a from Item a where a.name = :searchString;
select a from Item a join a.tags t where t.name = :searchString;
```

The most obvious-to-me way I could combine them is this:

```
select a from Item a where a.name = :searchString or a.id in (select b.id from Item b join b.tags t where t.name = :searchString);
```

This produces the correct result - however, the SQL it generates causes our MySQL database to perform a full table scan over Item. Neither of the individual queries do so - it is the addition of the "in" clause that causes the scan. It is probably not ideal for me to do two separate hql selects and do a "poor man's union" in Java code on the result sets, as it would require a sweeping code change of our search functionality. Without access to unions, though, I am at a loss for other ways to combine the queries. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: a published schema and an `explain`. Plop `explain` in front of query

Comment: Here is the explained plan of the last query I mentioned - http://i.imgur.com/kKzzOSz.png .

item_rel_tag is a table that stores relationships between items and tags. It is defined in the mapping files as many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `left outer join tags` and OR leaving distinct values? Like this

```
select distinct a 
from Item a left outer join a.tags t 
where t.name = :searchString or a.name=:searchString;
```

Comment: Hibernate makes the following SQL out of this:
`SELECT DISTINCT item0_.* FROM fg_item item0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN fg_item_rel_tag tags1_ ON item0_.item_id=tags1_.item_id LEFT OUTER JOIN k_c_tag tag2_ ON tags1_.tag_id=tag2_.tag_id WHERE tag2_.name='tag1' OR item0_.name='tag1' ORDER BY item0_.name LIMIT 50;`
When explained, this produces an ALL scan over fg_item (possible_keys sees fg_item.name but does not use it; extra info says "Using temporary; Using filesort".) It returns the correct query, but still table scans.